# intent new activity

Tags: android

Sorry for stupid question... I try to integrate a notification bar on AlarmManager class (same code runs perfectly in a new activity).

```
Context context = getApplicationContext(); and
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmManager.class);
```

is not correct does this?

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat;
        CharSequence tickerText = "tickerText";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Title";
        CharSequence contentText = "Text";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmManager.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Well where is `getSystemService()` called? If it's from a `Receiver`, you need to do `context.getSystemService(ns)`

Comment: `getSystemService(ns);` that's an error?

Comment: @njzk2 The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type AlarmReceiver

Comment: look at A--C's comment above

Comment: @PolHallen I don't think you need the `getApplicationContext()`, since you already have a `Context` provided by the `onReceive()` method which should be used.

Comment: @PolHallen if my answer did indeed solve your issue, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `context.getSystemService(ns)` where context is the variable that is passed to onCreate.